# request data httpClient Angular

Tags: rxjs, angular-httpclient

I want to request api with HttpClient angular,please show me how to do the same with async/await axios:

```
const requestApi = async (url) =>{
   return await axios.get(url);
} 
const dosmth = async (res)=>{
    // do smth;
}

const onSubmit = async()=>{
   const res = await requestApi(url);
   await dosmth(res);
}
```

Comment: Do you simply want to make a GET request to a server? The documentation covers this in depth…

Answer (score 0):

here is the way. you can use **Promise** with observable. get() method simple return observable.

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getConfig() {
  return this.http.get<Config>(URL);
}

const onSubmit = async () => {
  const res = this.getConfig().toPromise().then((data) => {}).catch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Angular, it is highly recommended that you use, Observables , RxJS and HTTP Client methods provided by Angular rather than using Promises.

This is a good way of making API Calls if you are not into NgRx and store management.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({ provideIn: 'root' })

export class YourServiceName {

 constructor (private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

 getConfig(): Observable<Config> {
   return this.httpClient.get<Config>(url).pipe(
        catchError((errorResponse: any) => this.handleError(errorResponse))
      );
 }

  /** Handle Error Response for the API Get Call */
  handleError(errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<any> {
    return throwError(errorResponse);
  }

}
--------------------------

// When you are using this service in any component, you can simply inject it using Dependency Injection and use this: Something like this: 

export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor(private configService: YourServiceName) {}

  // You can either use your config Service this way OR
   yourComponentMethod() {
     this.configService.getConfig().subscribe(apiResponse => {
       console.log('API Response ==>', apiResponse)
     }, apiErrorResponse => {
        console.log('API Error Response ==>', apiErrorResponse);
     })
  }

 // You can use your config Service this way 
   yourComponentMethod() {
     this.configService.getConfig()
       .pipe(catchError(apiErrorResponse => {
        console.log('API Error Response ==>', apiErrorResponse);
        }))
       .subscribe(apiResponse => {
         console.log('API Response ==>', apiResponse)
       })
  }

}

// This way you have ways and means of unsubscribing the observable / subscription etc. 

// If you use Promises, even writing test cases would be tough for that. Just an FYI
```